# On mouseleave of one div AND mouseenter of other div when both condition true

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, qmouseevent

There is 4 divs like following

```
<style>
    .displayNoneIcon {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div id="div1" style="float: left">
    <div id="div11">hello</div>
    <div id="div12">hi</div>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="float: right">
    <div id="div21" class="displayNoneIcon"><a href="#">bye</a></div>
    <div id="div22" class="displayNoneIcon"><a href="#">see ya</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to show div 21 when i hover on div11, dev22 on hover of div12, just like menu it should stay and clickable. If i move out from div11 then div21 must hide, except user enters into div21. Currently if i move out my pointer out of div11 towards div21 its hiding. i want it to be stayed.
Both must be in separate div like above.

I tried with mouseenter and mouseleave but its not fulfilling my requirement. Please help me with this.

```
$( "body" ).on( "mouseenter", "#div11", function(event) {
    $( "#div21" ).removeClass( "displayNoneIcon" );
});
$( "body" ).on( "mouseleave", "#div11", function(event) {
    $( "#div21" ).addClass( "displayNoneIcon" );
});
$( "body" ).on( "mouseenter", "#div12", function(event) {
    $( "#div22" ).removeClass( "displayNoneIcon" );
});
$( "body" ).on( "mouseleave", "#div12", function(event) {
    $( "#div22" ).addClass( "displayNoneIcon" );
});
```

Thanks in advance.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpbhat86/AWCn3/3/) link

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y34Xu/)) seems to do what you describe. Could you explain better?

Comment: As @blex says, it works just fine.

Comment: .show() and .hide() do the same as adding and removing a class with display:none;

Comment: Indeed. Could you post a working buggy jsFiddle?

Comment: Is [**this JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y34Xu/1/) doing what you want? (There is a container. If you leave this container, it hides everything. If not, it keeps the last hovered element's related div shown)

Comment: hi blex, thanks for the reply. in the JS fiddle output you cant click the links, when i move out from div11 and 12 the div 21/22 get hidden, i want it to be displayed and clickable.. Like menu submenu....

Comment: Hi @blex, Thanks again, but As per my requirement, I can have external container. without External container how can i make it work..?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this for learning reasons is to use an observer pattern in javascript.

[Observer pattern wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

[Here is an example tutorial doing this in javascript](https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/)

From my point of view you will want to fire a function on mouse-over/mouse-out that broadcasts the status, then functions subscribed to that broadcast can update the show/hide status of the divs.
This is also more recyclable than what you have in your question above.

Goodluck!